# Trie tree definition using lambda and defaultdict

Tags: python, lambda, trie

I thought below trie tree definition may have infinite recursive definition loop, since Trie is defined by Trie, etc. But I tried, it seems ok. Wondering why there is no infinite recursive definition loop?

```
Trie = lambda: collections.defaultdict(Trie)
root = Trie()
cur = root
for c in 'hello':
    cur = cur[c]
```

Comment: btw your loop is wrong, you lose the original reference to `root`

Comment: ...also, you're just defining `Trie` as a function that returns a default dict. There's nothing there that causes the function to call itself.

Comment: @MarkMeyer, but when python tries to resolve the function defined by lambda, it may try to resolve `Trie` in `collections.defaultdict(Trie)`, and trying to resolve `Trie` may cause infinite loop of definitions?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga updated

Comment: @LinMa no, why would it? It merely looks in the global scope for a name, which is defined already.

Comment: Defining a `lambda` is the same as defining a function, it's body is not executed when it is defined only when it is called

Comment: Yes, indeed, this *should* be a normal function definition if you want to follow standard python style guidelines

Comment: @LinMa it's not clear what you mean by `it may try to resolve`. Regardless, it certainly won't *call* `Trie` until you actually create a new key in default dict, which you don't do until you start the loop.

Comment: to have infinity recursion you would have to use `()` in `defaultdict( Trie() )`. Without `()` it uses only reference to `Trie` but it doesn't run it again. You will get recursion when you run `root = Trie()`